# Get number of characters read by sscanf?

Tags: c, string-parsing, scanf

I'm parsing a string (a `char*`) and I'm using `sscanf` to parse numbers from the string into doubles, like so:

```
// char* expression;
double value = 0;
sscanf(expression, "%lf", &value);
```

This works great, but I would then like to continue parsing the string through conventional means. I need to know how many characters have been parsed by `sscanf` so that I may resume my manual parsing from the new offset.

Obviously, the easiest way would be to somehow calculate the number of characters that `sscanf` parses, but if there's no simple way to do that, I *am* open to alternative double parsing options. However, I'm currently using `sscanf` because it's fast, simple, and readable. Either way, I just need a way to evaluate the double and continue parsing after it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use the format specifier `%n` and provide an additional `int *` argument to `sscanf()`:

```
int pos;
sscanf(expression, "%lf%n", &value, &pos);
```

Description for format specifier `n` from the C99 standard:

> No input is consumed. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the `fscanf` function**. Execution of a `%n` directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the `fscanf` function. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion specification includes an assignment suppressing character or a field width, the behavior is undefined.

Always check the return value of `sscanf()` to ensure that assignments were made, and subsequent code does not mistakenly process variables whose values were unchanged:

```
/* Number of assignments made is returned,
   which in this case must be 1. */
if (1 == sscanf(expression, "%lf%n", &value, &pos))
{
    /* Use 'value' and 'pos'. */
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work for the [Microsoft implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as such: `sscanf_s(p, "%s %d\n%n", toString, (int)_countof(toString), &itemCount, &pos);` The `pos` doesn't seem to change at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
int i, j, k;
char s[20];

if (sscanf(somevar, "%d %19s %d%n", &i, s, &j, &k) != 3)
    ...something went wrong...
```

The variable `k` contains the character count up to the point where the end of the integer stored in `j` was scanned.

Note that the `%n` is not counted in the successful conversions.  You can use `%n` several times in the format string if you need to.