# Is there a way to use the C standard library to convert string----->int and keep track number of characters parsed?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have a helper function in my program that is

```
long parse_int (char * cp, int * i)
{
/* 
    Helper function

    cp: Pointer to a character array that is a base-10 string representation of an integer
     i: Pointer to an integer which will store the output of the parsing of cp

    Returns the number of characters parsed.
*/

    long n = 0;
    *i = 0;
    while (cp!= '\0')
    {
        char c = *cp;
        long k = index_of(digits, c);
        if (k > -1)
        {
            n = n * 10 + k;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        ++cp;
    }
    return n;
}
```

where the stuff used inside it is

```
long index_of (char * pc, char c)
{
/*
   Helper function

   pc: Pointer to the first character of a character array
    c: Character to search

   Returns the index of the first instance of
   character c in the character array str. If
   none is found, returns -1.
*/
    char * pfoc = strchr(pc, c); /* Pointer to the first occurrence of character c */
    return pfoc ? (pfoc - pc) : -1;
}
```

and

```
char digits [] = "0123456789";
```

If possible, I'd like to cut down on the amount of code by maximizing the use of standard library firepower. I'm fully aware of `atoi`, but the problem is that I can't invoke it and recover the number of characters it parsed when it was invoked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503135/get-number-of-characters-read-by-sscanf dup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html), but you have to do a bit of work to be reasonably safe:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int strtoi(const char *data, char **endptr, int base)
{
    int old_errno = errno;
    errno = 0;
    long lval = strtol(data, endptr, base);
    if (lval > INT_MAX)
    {
        errno = ERANGE;
        lval = INT_MAX;
    }
    else if (lval < INT_MIN)
    {
        errno = ERANGE;
        lval = INT_MIN;
    }
    if (errno == 0)
        errno = old_errno;
    return (int)lval;
}
```

This is my `strtoi()` function which uses the standard `strtol()` to do the hard work.  It is careful not to (permanently) set `errno` to 0 since none of the standard library functions do that.  You use it like:

```
char *end;
int intval = strtoi(str, &end, 0);
```

Or you can be sloppy and just use:

```
char *end;
int intval = strtol(str, &end, 0);
```

The difference comes when the 'subject' string is larger than fits in an `int` but not larger than fits in a `long`; the `strtoi()` function clamps the returned value to `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`, but the sloppy technique typically just gives you the low-order 4 bytes of whatever value was stored in the `long`, which can be misleading if you have 64-bit `long` and 32-bit `int` values.

Note that the calling code should check for `intval == INT_MAX` or `intval == INT_MIN` and `errno != 0` to detect overflows.

You can write your `parse_int()` function in terms of this:

```
long parse_int (char *cp, int *i)
{
    char *end;
    *i = strtoi(cp, &end, 10);  // You want decimal
    return(end - cp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) instead of atoi.  The function signature for strtol has an outparameter to indicate the first invalid (non-digit) character)

```
 long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

So then you can just say this:

```
const char* pszNumber = "8942468XYZ";
char* pszEnd = NULL;
long val = strtol(pszNumber, &pszEnd, 10);

// pszEnd now points to "XYZ"
int number_of_characters_parsed = (int)(pszEnd - pszNumber);
```

Comment: How does that pointer subtraction work if pszEnd is NULL after running strtol?

Comment: As per: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol : `If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid character in *endptr. If there were no digits at all, strtol() stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0). In particular, if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return, the entire string is valid.`

Comment: In other words, I don't think it's expected that strtol will ever set endptr to NULL.  Are you observing something different?  Perhaps endptr will be returned as NULL if you pass in NULL.  But if you pass in a string that has no invalid characters, then endptr will point to the null terminator in the string.  So the the above `pszEnd-pszNumber` still works.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtoX` family of functions are considered better than `atoX` for this very reason.

You can provide a pointer to a variable which will receive the address of the first character that "failed" in the conversion.

The number of characters used in the conversion is then the difference between this value and the string itself (first character). In the code below, that would be `nextChar - str`.

For example, this is one way to check that an *entire* string is a valid long:

```
char *str = "12345";   // use your own test data here.
char *nextChar;
long val = strtol (str, &nextChar, 10);
if ((nextChar == str) || (*nextChar != '\0')) {
    printf ("Invalid input '%s'\n", str);
    return -1;
}
```

The two failure conditions are:

- The next char is the start of the string, no characters were used, needed because the next test actually allows an empty string.
- The next char isn't end of string, hence not all characters were consumed.